ReferenceError: exports is not defined [googleapis, Remix]
Repo: https://github.com/keigo9/Prana-Cottage/tree/feature/calendar-component
I can't use googleapis in loader function with Shopify Hydrogen app by Remix.
error code
import {google} from 'googleapis';

npm run dev error
Warning: Could not find ts-node at /Users/hoge/prana-
 ›   cottage/node_modules/@shopify/cli/dist/index-e6f8190d.js.
 ›   Please ensure that ts-node is a devDependency. Falling back to
 ›    compiled source.
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at /Users/hoge/prana-cottage/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js:15:23

googleapis/build/src/index.js:15:23 is here
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

npm run build error
RollupError: [commonjs--resolver] [plugin vite:resolve] Cannot bundle Node.js built-in "fs" imported
    from "node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/discovery.js". Consider disabling ssr.noExternal or
    remove the built-in dependency.

vite.config.js not work
ssr: {
    noExternal: ['fs', 'googleapis', 'googleapis-common'],
  },

In node_modules of googleapi, all require can't work
const fs = require("fs");

Read it and try it not work: Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined
vite-plugin-require[https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-require] can't work

Same issue here, ReferenceError: exports is not defined when attempting to import firebase-admin/app from within an exported action in Remix. Other answers suggested this was due to the modules getting imported client side, but the issue persists even when using dynamic import() from inside the action function.
